# IdWhois result with Unicode characters

Tags: delphi

I'm using IdWhois to work with the [RFC954](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc954.txt) protocol.
When the result contains Unicode characters like "é, ó, ç...", I just get a question mark "�" instead of the char. I usually have difficulties when need to make string conversion into Delphi. Tried examples found on Google, but no success. So right now I'm thinking maybe the protocol works only with ASCII chars? No idea.

Original code, without any try of conversion (none of them worked anyway), running on Delphi 10 Seattle:

```
var
  Whois: TIdWhois;
  RequestResult: String;
begin
  Whois:= TIdWhois.Create(Nil);
  Whois.ReadTimeout:= 10000;
  Whois.ConnectTimeout:= 10000;
  try
    Whois.Host:= WhoisServer;
    try
      RequestResult:= Whois.WhoIs(URL);
      ...
```

If I add RequestResult to a Memo, or while debugging, I just get the question mark instead of the Unicode characters.

Comment: Nobody? Looks like IdWhois doesn't support ISO-8859-1, because I discovered the server I was querying uses this encoding.

Comment: Do you want to query Whois server for IDN - domains which contain Unicode chars?

Comment: No. I want to query Whois that the result comes with Unicode chars. The solution I found was using IdTCPClient instead of IdWhois, and doing the query manually over whois protocol, setting IdTCPClient Default Charset to ISO-8859-1...